# Turborepo/pnpm workspaces: build my package and every package I depend on

Tags: pnpm, turborepo, pnpm-workspace

I have three packages in my turborepo monorepo, `top`, `middle`, and `bottom`.  `top` depends on `middle` and `middle` depends on `bottom`.

If I do this:

```
cd bottom
make some edits
cd ../middle
make some edits
```

I want to type something in that directory (`middle`) that will build everything that `middle` depends on (i.e. `bottom`) and `middle` itself.

I know I can cd to the root of the project and do this:

`turbo run build --filter=middle...`

but I want a command (or a script) that knows what directory I am in and basically says "build everything up to and including here"

Answer (score 0):

In case it's of use to any one, I added this to by `.zshrc`:

```
find-up () {
  path=$(pwd)
  while [[ "$path" != "" && ! -e "$path/$1" ]]; do
    path=${path%/*}
  done
  echo "$path"
}


bt () {
    ROOT_DIR=$(find-up "pnpm-workspace.yaml")
    PKG_NAME=$(npm pkg get name | sed -e s#\"##g)
    (cd $ROOT_DIR && pnpm run build --filter=$PKG_NAME...)
}
```

Now I can cd into `middle` and type `bt` (standing for build to) and it will build everything up to and including the current package.  Would love to know a better way!

Answer (score 0):

According to [TurboRepo's documentation](https://turbo.build/repo/docs/core-concepts/monorepos/running-tasks#in-a-different-workspace), you simply need to add `"dependsOn": ["^build"]` to the `pipeline.build` in turbo.json.
When you run `npm run build` on the monorepo top folder, it should build in order according to the dependencies of each workspace.

Here is an example for the `turbo.json` file.

```
{
  "$schema": "https://turbo.build/schema.json",
  "pipeline": {
    "build": {
      // "A workspace's `build` command depends on its dependencies'
      // and devDependencies' `build` commands being completed first"
      "dependsOn": ["^build"],
      "outputs": [".next/**", "!.next/cache/**"]
    }
  }
```